# Magento 2 not able to get creditmemo collection

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, creditmemo

I am trying to get credit memo collection with following script but am unable to get the collection

```
class Creditmemosync extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

protected $helper;

protected $logger;

protected $resourceConfig;

protected $creditmemoRepository;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
                            \VestricsM2\Connector\Helper\Data $helper,
                            \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $resourceConfig,
                            \Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface $creditmemoRepository,
                            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->helper = $helper;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->resourceConfig = $resourceConfig;
    $this->creditmemoRepository = $creditmemoRepository;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

 public function execute(){
    $creditmemos = $this->creditmemoRepository->getList(); 
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($creditmemos);
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you remove var/generation folder from root?

Comment: yes i am deleting var folder before upgrade & compile

Comment: getList() method not working

Comment: try with, $creditmemos = $this->creditmemoRepository->getList(); 
foreach($creditmemos as $credit){
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($credit->getData());
}

Comment: Once again i deleted var folder and done upgrade & compile still am getting 500 error